# What is the proper format of adding in multiple SSID's into wpa_supplicant.conf?

Tags: wifi, raspi-config

What is the proper format of adding in multiple SSID's? I have the following below. Do I add a comma like in JSON format?

```ini
    # For more configuration option please see:
    # https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    
    ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
    ctrl_interface_group=0
    ap_scan=1
    
    network={
    ssid="x"
        # Uncomment to connect to Hidden SSIDs
        #scan_ssid=1 
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP WEP104 WEP40
        psk="_______"
        priority=2
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os)

Answer (score 0):

You add multiple network stanzas.

What you have listed is incorrect for the Pi (and most Linux OS) - among other things you omitted Country Code.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697

Answer (score 0):

The proper format to be followed is defined in the manuals for `wpa_supplicant`, and `wpa_supplicant.conf`; e.g. `man wpa_supplicant`. You can also find a good *explanatory* document for building your own `wpa_supplicant.conf` file in your **local** filesystem at: **`/usr/share/doc/wpa_supplicant/examples/wpa_supplicant.conf`**

It's not JSON...

In the simplest case, something like this may suffice for small, personal networks:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="WiFiNetworkUpstairs" 
        psk="WiFiPasswordForUpstairs"
}  
network={
        ssid="DownstairsWiFiNetwork"
        psk="WiFiPasswordForDownstairs"  
}
network={
        ssid="AnotherWiFiNetwork"
        psk="AnotherWiFiPassword"
}
# etc, etc, etc
```